# Azure function app processing same message 2 times

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a function app which is working on Service Bus Topic binding, i am observing issue on our QC environment with function app trigger is processing the same message 2 times. the overall execution of request is 9 to 10 second.

First i thought it maybe due to the lock expiry message is getting process twice. after analyzing the request logs i found the difference between in both the invocation is 2 second.

The lock duration is set as 5 minutes, and max retry is 1.

```
[FunctionName("RequestToBizTalk")] 
public static async Task RunAsync(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("%topic-name%", "%topic-subscriber-Biztalk%", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionKey")]
    BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage, 
    ExecutionContext executionContext, 
    ILogger log) 
{ 
    //Business logic as per the message content 
}
```

Comment: How are you reading from the subscription? Some code would be good.

Comment: I am using azure function app service bus topic binding. and AccessRights.Manage

Comment: Sorry but you really need to post some code.

Comment: [FunctionName("RequestToBizTalk")]
        public static async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("%topic-name%", "%topic-subscriber-Biztalk%", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionKey")]BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage, ExecutionContext executionContext, ILogger log)
        {
   //Business logic as per the message content
  }

Comment: Can you put the code in the question, please?

Comment: I have added function app code in question

Answer (score 0):

I tried the combination of Service Bus Queue binding with Service Bus Premium namespace and same message processing was not occurred for any instance.

Load size combination are 1000 request 2 times, and 500 request 4 times, and 250 request 8 times.

with service bus topic and premium namespace I found function app is failing with service bus connectivity & Host thresholds exceeded errors. with load size of 100 and above messages.

[image]